# RXJava - continuously emit values for determined period

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a heart-rate sensor that emits a value periodically (anywhere between 500-3000 milli). When the heart rate sensor emits is non-deterministic. With RXJava, i would like to have a constant emitting the 'last seen' heart rate value and the constant emits the value for up to 10 Seconds until it marks it as too-stale & sends a NULL instead. NULL denotes that the heart rate sensor is no longer emitting sensor readings.

I have the following (kotlin) code:

```
    val heartRateObservable: Observable<BLEDataValue> = observable
            .flatMap { it.setupNotification(characteristic.uniqueIdentifier) }
            .flatMap { it }
            .map { BTDataPacket(characteristic.uniqueIdentifier, BleParseable(it)).btValue() }.onErrorReturn { BLEDataValueHeartRate(null) }
    return Observable.combineLatest(Observable.interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), heartRateObservable, BiFunction { _, t2 -> t2 })
```

Question: Is it possible to introduce a way to replay the last seen heart-rate value up to when the last value becomes stale (i.e. after not seeing any heart-rate readings for 10 seconds).. when a heart rate value is seen it replay this until a new heart-rate value arrives OR the timeout of 10 seconds passes as the last value is now too-stale?

Comment: Do you want something that will emit data on an interval till 10000 milliseconds?

Comment: you want to emit values each 1 sec for a period of 10 sec and then complete or send null ? is that what you want ?

Comment: Thanks - updated question..

Comment: @Mannie, so you want to replay the last seen heart-rate value each second for 10 sec or replace it by the new one arrived (within 10 sec) ? If so I updated my answer

Comment: @bubbles - correct, i want to replay the 'last seen' heart-rate sensor value & If no new sensor value is 'seen' within the 10second window, chances are the heart rate sensor has disconnected (or user had turned off) so notify the user of this. within that 10 second window i'm looking a constant uniform stream of sensor values hence replaying the last seen value - the 10sec window resets everytime the sensor value is updated.

Comment: @Mannie so what is missing in my solution below ? It replays the last seen rate value for 10 secs and stops if no value is recieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `takeWhile` or `takeUntil` operators to complete your rate observable.

wait for 10 emissions :

```java
Observable heartbeat = Observable.interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.takeWhile(e -> e < 10)
```

or by using a `timer` witj `takeUntil`

```java
Observable heartbeat = Observable.interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.takeUntil(Observable.timer(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
```

After that you said :

> ... and emit this for up to 10,000 Milliseconds from the last received sensor value after ...

For that you can use `switchMap` (If I've understood your question)

```java
heartRateObservable
.switchMap(data -> heartbeat.map(data))
```

Hence the heartbeat starts emitting values after each last emitted data.

```kotlin
val heartRateObservable: Observable<BLEDataValue> = observable
            .flatMap { it.setupNotification(characteristic.uniqueIdentifier) }
            .flatMap { it }
            .map { BTDataPacket(characteristic.uniqueIdentifier, BleParseable(it)).btValue() }.onErrorReturn { BLEDataValueHeartRate(null) }
return heartRateObservable
       .switchMap { data -> Observable.interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                     .takeWhile(e -> e < 10) 
                     .map(l -> data)
                  }
```